# how to DBCC CHECKIDENT RESEED with a negtative value

Tags: t-sql, azure-synapse

I want to reseed my identity column starting with a negtative value.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.myTable', RESEED, 1);
```

This works perfectly fine, however:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.myTable', RESEED, -1);
```

fails with

> Msg 104366, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
>   Reseed values should be provided in the DBCC CheckIdent Statement.

Even though the syntax looks identical. Creating a new table with a negative seed value also works fine.

How do I do this?

Comment: Share your table definition. Is the -1 lower than the initial seed in the table definition?

Comment: @dfundako it's the same value as originally seeded with

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
CREATE TABLE testident (id INT IDENTITY(-1, 1), fname VARCHAR(100))
GO 
INSERT INTO testident (fname)
VALUES 
('david'),
('mark'),
('bill'),
('jane')

DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.testident', RESEED, -2);

INSERT INTO testident (fname)
VALUES 
('david'),
('mark'),
('bill'),
('jane')

select * 
from testident
```

Comment: Is this on Azure Data Warehouse? I get the same error.

Comment: @NeilP Ahhh no its just on a SQL Server 2017 database/container. Not Azure.But the docs say it should be compatible with Azure DW at the top: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Do you have permissions? From the doc: Azure SQL Data Warehouse requires db_owner permissions.

Comment: I've got db_owner - reseeding with a positive integer value works fine.